# Will protractor afterEach not run a jasmine timeout happens?

Tags: timeout, protractor

I am new to protractor and any response helps!!
I see this
 Message:
     timeout: timed out after 30000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

and I have afterEach cleans my test data. My log messages there are not being printed. Seems like it does not run afterEach. 
Also will afterEach be called when a test test fails normally (without timeout but other error)? If yes, is there a way for me to check for test result being pass or fail and do some cleanup actions based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Jasmine does not execute the `afterEach` block in the case of a timeout.

You can see how to hook up some code to run when a Jasmine test fails in the Protractor FAQ:  https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-screenshots-of-failures